# Chrome allows a connection without a browser certificate, but shouldn't

Tags: java, google-chrome, ssl, certificate, keystore

I am attempting to test a secure websocket connection from a Java server to an Angular client. The server uses a keystore I created by importing a self-signed certificate, which I created using OpenSSL. The client is supposed to display an error if the client connection fails.

For IE, Edge, and Firefox, if I do not install the browser certificate, I get a browser warning first, then if navigate to the site, I see the error. This is what I would expect.

For Chrome, I get the warning page "Your connection is not private" with the error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. If I then proceed to the site, it comes up without an error. My code shows that a connection is established. I didn't expect this to occur.

At first, I thought I had an old certificate installed in the browser. However, Chrome uses the same certificate store as IE and Edge, and they work. Still, I cleared the SSL cache and even uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome. It still didn't show the error.

Can anyone give me any suggestions as to why Chrome is allowing this connection without the browser certificate?

Comment: It is unclear for me what exact error you expect. Chrome `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` is the error about an untrusted certificate but as you said you explicitly ignore this error and proceed. What additional error did you expect and why?

Comment: You may have misconfigured something, besides the certificate not being recognized which is expected since it is a self signed one. If you configure a TLS server to require a certificate from client, and if it has various validation rules on the certificate received from client (like for example what is the CA), then if the client does not send a certificate or not correct one per server rules, then the server should/will close the TLS handshake and no content will ever be exchanged at all. There is nothing the client can do (besides sending the proper certificate) to circumvent that.

Comment: Clarification:

All browsers show an error when I first navigate to the site. In all cases, I can ignore the web error and proceed to the site.

The site runs an Angular app containing a service that manages a websocket connection (an RxJS WebSocketSubject) with Observable functions next, error, and complete. If the app tries to connect to the server without a certificate (for a browser other than Chrome), the error function is triggered, and I put up a dialog indicating that the connection is not working.

Chrome, by contrast, allows the connection to complete.

Comment: Replying to Patrick: I can check to see if the server requires a certificate from the client. I thought it was doing that, but I may have missed something. Would this explain why Chrome is the only one that accepts the connection?